# Python Flask - Non ascii characters in API Get Endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, utf-8

I have a back end application built in Python Flask with an api endpoint: /api/getdata/ where name can contain Swedish letters such as Å,Ä and Ö. When I try to use these in the API call using curl in my prompt the Swedish characters turn up like question marks in Python 3.6. But when I do this in Python 2.7 with this in the beginning of my script it works:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

How can I solve this? I am already using the utf-8 comment line in the beginning of the script.

*** UPDATE ***

This works in Python 2 with the above workaround but not in Python 3:

```
app.route('/api/getdata/<name>')
def hello_world(name):
    print(name) # Gives correct in Python 2.7, just a question mark in Python 3
    return name
```

Request:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/api/getdata/Åland
```

Comment: Are the non-ASCII characters part of the route?

Comment: They are a part of the Input parameters in the get request. So yes they are a part of the route @lenz

Comment: You need to identify if this problem is produced (a) when decoding input (the query parameters here) or (b) when exporting the result (eg. writing to a log file). It could even be (c) that everything with the application is fine, you're just using the wrong tool to view the result (eg. Notepad on Windows, which doesn't like UTF-8).

Comment: Either you figure it out yourself, or you provide more information. All the code you show here is a deprecated strategy for making STD I/O work with UTF-8 (ie. it is unrelated to the parsing of the request data).

Comment: When I try the APIs in a browser with the Python 2.7 workaround they are working. When I do the same with Python 3 it doesn’t work. The same goes for trying it in the command line. This means it has to be connected to the env itself. Probably maybe my utf-8 comment on top of the script is wrong or something..? @lenz

Comment: Updated question now @lenz

Comment: Are you sure that curl automatically url-encodes the "Å" properly? Can you show the output, including headers (`curl -i`)? Maybe you have to pipe the response body through `hexdump -C` to be sure it's not your terminal that messes up the characters.

Comment: It works in Python 2.7 with the exact same request so the problem is not in the curl request. @lenz

Comment: The headers show how flask encodes the response body, in the "charset=" part of the content-type header.

Comment: When I print ’name’ before I return it, it is the same, works för Python 2.7, question mark for 3 @lenz

Comment: Would you mind doing `print(repr(name))` and copy-paste the result here? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Getting a proper-looking output from a Python-2 print statement doesn't necessarily mean the input is handled correctly. It could be a symmetric pair of faulty de-/encoding. If you want me to help you with getting it right in Python 3, you need to show the information I asked for.